# Salvar Formulário PDF - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

Gostaria de salvar o formulário em PDF ou imprimir mas manter o layout exibido na tela.
Exemplo:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationDefault01">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationDefault01" placeholder="First name" value="Mark" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationDefault02">Last name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationDefault02" placeholder="Last name" value="Otto" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationDefaultUsername">Username</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend2">@</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationDefaultUsername" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend2" required>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label for="validationDefault03">City</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationDefault03" placeholder="City" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <label for="validationDefault04">State</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationDefault04" placeholder="State" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <label for="validationDefault05">Zip</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationDefault05" placeholder="Zip" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck2" required>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck2">
        Agree to terms and conditions
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>




    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Na tela

[image: Tela]

Ao tentar imprimir o bootstrap redimensiona e coloca um campo embaixo do outro.

[image: Tela Impressao]

Preciso que saia com o layout exibido.

Comment: o estilo para impressão é diferente do que é renderizado para a tela. Você pode definir como vai ficar o estilo da impressão usando no css `@media print { ... estilos ...}`. Também pode tentar usar o mesmo estilo para tela e impressão. Na tag `<link>` você pode adicionar `media="all"`, porque pode ser que o estilo esteja sendo usado só para tela (pode ser que esteja definido como `media="screen"`)

Answer (score 2):

Você vai precisar de programar efetivamente o layout do seu documento PDF.

Isso pode ser feito de diversas formas, em várias linguagens ou ainda usando algum serviço para isso.

Veja essa opção de uma API que converte html para pdf... pode ser bastante útil.

http://pdfmyurl.com/html-to-pdf-api

Caso esteja usando PHP, temos a biblioteca FPDF que é excelente...

http://www.fpdf.org/

Mas tem que ser feito tudo via código....

```
class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Page header
function Header()
{
    // Logo
    $this->Image('logo.png',10,6,30);
    // Arial bold 15
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
    // Move to the right
    $this->Cell(80);
    // Title
    $this->Cell(30,10,'Title',1,0,'C');
    // Line break
    $this->Ln(20);
}

// Page footer
function Footer()
{
    // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}
}

// Instanciation of inherited class
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++)
    $pdf->Cell(0,10,'Printing line number '.$i,0,1);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode definir as colunas para media print manualmente, seguindo o que já está estabelecido no Bootstrap, como por exemplo:

```
@media print {
   .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
        float: left;
   }
   .col-md-12 {
        width: 100%;
   }
   .col-md-11 {
        width: 91.66666667%;
   }
   .col-md-10 {
        width: 83.33333333%;
   }
   .col-md-9 {
        width: 75%;
   }
   .col-md-8 {
        width: 66.66666667%;
   }
   .col-md-7 {
        width: 58.33333333%;
   }
   .col-md-6 {
        width: 50%;
   }
   .col-md-5 {
        width: 41.66666667%;
   }
   .col-md-4 {
        width: 33.33333333%;
   }
   .col-md-3 {
        width: 25%;
   }
   .col-md-2 {
        width: 16.66666667%;
   }
   .col-md-1 {
        width: 8.33333333%;
   }
}
```

Você também pode (e deve) usar as classes já definidas no Bootstrap pra ocultar ou exibir elementos somente na impressão:

- `.visible-print-block`
- `.visible-print-inline`
- `.visible-print-inline-block`
- `.hidden-print`